# How to manage nested looping and storing returns with postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of users and a table of assets. For each asset in the table of assets I need to get the users who have access to that asset (simple join). From these users I need to have a reference to the earliest user who gained access to this asset (there exists a created column already)

For each of those users I need to get their parent company (multiple joins).

I need to store each users id, asset they have access to, and parent company into a new table. In this new table I need to flag each user according to whether they were the earliest user or not.

What is an efficient method to handle this situation in postgreSQL? Can I do all of this in one go or do I need to make functions or? Unfortunately I have to use postgreSQL only. This logic is simple to implement if I could use PHP or C# but I cannot.

Sample Tables:

USER TABLE

[image]

ASSET TABLE

[image]

COMPANY TABLE

[image]

USER ASSET ACCESS TABLE

[image]

EXPECTED RESULTS

[image]

NOTE: I simplified the problem with that company table. Theres no table that just lists a users parent company but I can figure that out myself

The gained_asset_access_first column is based on the user asset access table. The user that has the earliest created date for user_asset_access is flagged as true for gained_asset_access_first, all users who gained access to that asset at a later date are flagged as false.

Comment: Yes, it can be done in one go. Please post a few rows of sample data and the expected result, so we can give you an exact solution for the case.

Comment: @TheImpaler ty, i have added sample data, please let me know if I can provide additional detail

Comment: By the way PostgreSQL is an excellent database, not as high end as Oracle or DB2 (that have many bells and whistles) but far superior than SQL Server or MySQL. It's a great choice... and it's free. Can't beat the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I invented the dates so the result can be a bit different:

```
with
f as (
  select distinct on (asset_id) asset_id, created, user_id
  from user_asset_access
  order by asset_id, created desc
)
select u.user_id, a.asset_id, c.company_id, f.user_id as first_user_id,
  u.user_id = f.user_id as gained_asset_access_first
from asset a
join user_asset_access s on s.asset_id = a.asset_id
join "user" u on u.user_id = s.user_id
left join f on f.asset_id = s.asset_id
left join company c on c.user_id = f.user_id
```

Result:

```
  user_id   asset_id   company_id   first_user_id   gained_asset_access_first  
 --------- ---------- ------------ --------------- --------------------------- 
  1         1          1            2               false                      
  1         5          1            1               true                       
  2         1          1            2               true                       
  2         3          1            2               true                       
  3         3          1            2               false
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gEZ1VYxykW7CFHzvmoVqh7/1). The data script I used is:

```
create table "user" (
  user_id int
);

insert into "user" (user_id) values (1), (2), (3);

create table asset (
  asset_id int,
  asset_data varchar(10)
);

insert into asset (asset_id, asset_data) values (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e');

create table company (
  company_id int,
  user_id int
);

insert into company (company_id, user_id) values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3);

create table user_asset_access (
  user_asset_access_is int,
  asset_id int,
  user_id int,
  created date
);

insert into user_asset_access (user_asset_access_is, asset_id, user_id, created) values
  (1, 1, 1, '2020-01-01'),
  (2, 1, 2, '2020-01-02'),
  (3, 3, 3, '2020-01-03'),
  (4, 3, 2, '2020-01-04'),
  (5, 5, 1, '2020-01-05');
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this should be more than enough to get me started

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function to achieve this:

```
select u.user_id, a.asset_id, c.company_id as company,
       1 = row_number() over (partition by uaa.asset_id
                                  order by uaa.created) as gained_asset_acces_first,
       a.asset_data
  from "user" u
       join company c
         on c.user_id = u.user_id
       join user_asset_access uaa
         on uaa.user_id = u.user_id
       join asset a
         on a.asset_id = uaa.asset_id
;
```

The join to `user` is not strictly necessary for your data, but I included it in case you wanted to add some other columns from that table.